# Can't Find Variable: "navigation" in react native

Tags: react-native

This is my code, I used some of it from youtube.

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, Button, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";

TouchableOpacity.defaultProps = { activeOpacity: 0.8 };

// touchableOpacity makes the button

const AppButton = ({ onPress, title }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => navigation.navigate("SignInScreen")}
    style={styles.appButtonContainer}
  >
    <Text style={styles.appButtonText}>{title}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

// Navigation should lead to SignInScreen

const App = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.screenContainer}>
      <AppButton title="Register" size="sm" backgroundColor="#007bff" />
    </View>
  );
};

// Styling Button and everything

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screenContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    padding: 16,
  },
  appButtonContainer: {
    elevation: 8,
    backgroundColor: "#009688",
    borderRadius: 10,
    height: 60,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 12,
  },
  appButtonText: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: "#fff",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    alignSelf: "center",
    textTransform: "uppercase",
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is expecting navigation object inside AppButton as well. I can see that you passed the navigation object as a prop to App. But, I don't see it inside AppButton.

```
const AppButton = ({ onPress, title,navigation }) => (

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('SignInScreen') style={styles.appButtonContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.appButtonText}>{title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

 );
```

Comment: Okay, so would I copy this code and replace the first Const AppButton?

Comment: Any luck with it @MosesCarbin

Comment: Sadly no. For some reason nothing works. @TrinadhKoya

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be declaring nor importing `navigation` from anywhere.
But assuming you are using react-navigation you should use the `useNavigation` hook. Like so:

```
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

const AppButton = ({ onPress, title }) => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignInScreen')} style=
            {styles.appButtonContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.appButtonText}>{title}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};
```

This also benefits from less confusion when having to pass down props to different components.